Cannot read a double nested directory
Essentially I'm trying to store all of file system in a certain dir in an array of objects. Here is my code:
type Cache = {
  path: string;
  content: Buffer;
};

const readdir = (dir: string, currentDir: string) => {
  const dirContent = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  const ignore = fs.readFileSync(".gitignore", "utf8").split("\n");
  ignore.push(".git");

  const cache: Cache[] = [];

  dirContentLoop: for (let i = 0; i < dirContent.length; i++) {
    const path = `${currentDir}/${dirContent[i]}`.replace("./", "");
    for (let j = 0; j < ignore.length; j++) {
      if (path === ignore[j]) {
        continue dirContentLoop;
      }
    }

    if (isDir(path)) {
      readdir(dirContent[i], path);
      continue;
    }

    cache.push({
      path: path,
      content: fs.readFileSync(path)
    });
  }

  global.cache = cache;
};


The function readdir takes in two params:

dir the dir to read
currentDir the current directory being read in

If a path is a directory the readdir function calls itself. However when I run the function I get an error:
node:fs:1509
  const result = binding.readdir(
                         ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'workflows'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1509:26)
    at readdir (/Users/ekrich/git/universal-fs/scripts/cache.ts:10:25)
    at readdir (/Users/ekrich/git/universal-fs/scripts/cache.ts:25:7)
    at readdir (/Users/ekrich/git/universal-fs/scripts/cache.ts:25:7)
    at cache (/Users/ekrich/git/universal-fs/scripts/cache.ts:39:3)
    at <anonymous> (/Users/ekrich/git/universal-fs/scripts/cache.ts:63:1)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:262:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:474:24)
    at async asyncRunEntryPointWithESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:109:5) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'workflows'
}

Node.js v22.3.0

What is wrong with my logic here?

This is really really good situation to learn step-through debugging with the chrome debugger. I'm sure that once you do the problem will jump out to you immediately.

@Evert I'm using node.js and therefor can't use the chrome debugger

yes you can! They are compatible.
